# How do I launch Windows Explorer from the WSL Bash command line?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Navigating between the WSL Bash shell and the Windows environment can be challenging because the path in windows is say:
`C:\Windows`
and in bash it is:
`/mnt/c/Windows`
Launching the Windows Explorer using the Current Working Directory (CWD) does not work by doing:
`start .`

What is the command that I should type?

Answer (score 3):

found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245721/launching-explorer-from-wsl

Essentially:

```
alias start='cmd.exe /c start'
```

then `start .` will work too.

**Note**: it will not start an explorer on linux only files, but any mapped windows file systems will work.

Comment: greetings from 2023: ```alias start='powershell.exe start' ``` will do the trick now

Answer (score 3):

As of now you just need to write

```
#!/bin/bash
explorer.exe
```

inside of your script.sh file and you can run it with

```
bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems by default /mnt/c/Windows is not in the bash path environment variable so the best so far is:
`/mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe .`